# How to get a value from the parent(s) of a tag using beautifulsoup / python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get a value from the parent(s) of a tag using beautifulsoup / python?

This is a snippet of my html

```
<div
                    class="c-grid__col js-product-package-dimension c-grid__col--gap-lg c-grid__col--flex-initial c-grid__col--lg-6">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="">
                        ابعاد بسته‌بندی (سانتیمتر):
                        <span class="uk-form-label__required"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="c-grid__row c-grid__row--gap-small c-grid__row--nowrap-sm">
                        <div class="c-grid__col c-grid__col--gap-small c-grid__col--flex-initial">
                            <div class="field-wrapper">
                                <label class="c-content-input">
                                    <span class="c-content-input__text c-content-input__text--overlay">طول</span>
                                    <input class="c-content-input__origin c-content-input__origin--overlay"
                                        name="product[package_length]" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c-grid__col c-grid__col--gap-small c-grid__col--flex-initial c-grid__col--xs-gap">
                            <div class="field-wrapper">
                                <label class="c-content-input">
                                    <span class="c-content-input__text c-content-input__text--overlay">عرض</span>
                                    <input class="c-content-input__origin c-content-input__origin--overlay"
                                        name="product[package_width]" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c-grid__col c-grid__col--gap-small c-grid__col--flex-initial c-grid__col--xs-gap">
                            <div class="field-wrapper">
                                <label class="c-content-input">
                                    <span class="c-content-input__text c-content-input__text--overlay">ارتفاع</span>
                                    <input class="c-content-input__origin c-content-input__origin--overlay"
                                        name="product[package_height]" placeholder="" type="text" value="" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am trying to extract its fields with bs4
But my problem is that their required value is the same as what I sent in the father and grandfather tags, how can I write my code correctly, I send my python code that works correctly but does not get the required value
Also, the required value is obtained from `uk-form-label__required`

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.has_attr('name') and tag['name'].startswith('product['))

        # Find the labels associated with the tags
        for tag in tags:
            # Assuming the label is in a div that comes before the input
            label = tag.find_previous('label')
            if label:
                # print(label.get_text(strip=True))
                temp_dict = {"source": "",
                             "id": tag['name'],
                             "title": label.get_text(strip=True),

                             }

                standard_json.append(temp_dict)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understad. What is the required output from the posted HTML snippet?